# How to pass an array into mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an array of variable length and i want to pass the array into mysql get query.

var ids = [1, 3, 7, 8]

And my query is

```
 return Connection.query("select student from registrations where id in (?)", [ids], callback);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Try to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to parse the array.
`return Connection.query("select student from registrations where id in (?)", ...ids, callback);`

Comment: @cdaiga not all of us can read german..

Comment: you can also try to use the Array join function. `return Connection.query("select student from registrations where id in (?)", ids.join(), callback);`  "The join() method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.

The elements will be separated by a specified separator. The default separator is comma (,)."

Comment: @RaymondNijland tried but it didn't work...=[

Comment: Hey his is the link in english: [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). @ekxz900 did you try this: `return Connection.query("select student from registrations where id in (?)", ...ids, callback);`?

Comment: @cdaiga yeap, i tried it as well but getting this error
TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\Ufinity\RESTAPIFInal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Ufinity\RESTAPIFInal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)

Comment: `ids.join()` should work but needs to be passed inside an array like this `return Connection.query("select student from registrations where id in (?)", [ids.join()], callback);`

Comment: Did you try @avpav approach? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts such as mapping and spread operator used directly on the array which is passed in, I use literal template to solve that, but it might has some potential security risk in SQLInjection.

```
return Connection.query(`select student from registrations where id in (ids.toString())`, callback);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes the query will works.

```
get_source_pass_oppartner_ridePoints:
    'SELECT * FROM ride_root WHERE rideId in (?)',
    return database.query( sql.get_source_pass_oppartner_ridePoints, [rideIds] )
```